# Cannot convert tex file into html in Centos

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I have this tex file: `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)--(1,0)--(0.5,2)--(0,0);
\draw(0,0)circle(1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I need to generate the `html`, so in Windows I execute: `htlatex test.tex` and it works. Now I want to do the same in a Centos machine.

I was trying with several commands. I tried:

```
htlatex test.tex
```

but it fails:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfsys@svg@newline ->\Hnewline

l.190   \pgfusepathqfill}
```

I tried:

```
mk4ht test.tex "html"
```

It fails:

```
mk4ht (Version 1.1)
improper command: test.tex
 option1:  mk4ht #1 "#2" "#3" "#4" "#5"

    #1: htlatex, xhlatex, mzlatex, oolatex, dblatex, dbmlatex,
        jhlatex, eslatex, teilatex, teimlatex, uxhlatex,
        wlatex, xhmlatex

        also 'tex', 'texi', 'context', 'xetex', and 'xelatex'
        instead of 'latex'
```

I tried:

```
tex4ht test.tex test.html
```

It fails:

```
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht test.tex
  test.html
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `test.dvi'
--- error --- Can't find/open file `test.dvi'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that your TeX distro is too old, this error was fixed several years ago.

Comment: You are showing 2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea  can you not install a tex system newer than that?